# recordset.find using variable VBA ADODB

Tags: ms-access, vba, find, recordset

I am getting pretty desperate trying to get this trivial search to work:

```
 rst2.Find "ID = '" & messID & "'"
```

I have tried just about any combination but it just never returns a search result. the whole code would be here:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Modul zum Updaten des Status eines Messmittels in der Stammdatenbank (Entnommen/Verfügbar)3

Public Function updateStatus()

Dim rst2 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim messID As String

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'Stammdaten zur Bearbeitung öffnen
            rst.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
            rst.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
            rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
            rst.Open "Stammdaten"
            rst.MoveFirst

Set rst2 = New ADODB.Recordset 'zur Bearbeitung öffnen
            rst2.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
            rst2.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
            rst2.LockType = adLockOptimistic
            rst2.Open "Verwendung"

Do While Not rst.EOF
            messID = rst!ID
            Debug.Print messID
            rst2.Find "ID = '" & messID & "'"
            If rst2.EOF = True Then 'Falls nicht vorhanden
                Debug.Print "Keine Verwendung gefunden!"
            Else
                rst2.Sort = "Nr DESC"
                rst2.MoveFirst
                Debug.Print rst2!Status
            End If
            rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
rst2.Close

End Function
```

What am I missing? I literally tried hunderds of diffrent search strings :(

Comment: Why don't you search with a complete query inside the table ?, ID it's a field from an access table right ?

Comment: I mean, like this : rst2.source="Select * from tablename where ID='" & messID & "'"

Comment: Sorry I am not that familiar with access and my access version is in german which doesn't help... I have one table containing unique ID's ("Stammdaten") I have another table containing multiple entrys for each ID ("Verwendung"). I am trying to get every entry for one ID at a time sort these entries and then only write one back to another table (not in the code yet) hope that helps a bit....
using a query wouldn't work since there are multiple entries for each ID :(

Comment: I see, try the line i posted you and tell me how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a table-type recordset and you're searching it by the key. This is the typical use-case for the `Seek` method instead of the `Find` method.

According to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/108149

> The find methods (FindFirst, FindLast, FindNext, and FindPrevious) apply to Dynasets and Snapshots but not to Table objects. Conversely, the Seek method is available only on the Table object.

Although that page seems focused on DAO more than ADO, but the same logic should  apply to both cases.

I think you should try the `Seek` method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675109(v=vs.85).aspx

```
rst2.Seek "=", messID
If rst2.NoMatch Then ' not found ...
```

Comment: Seek unfortunatly doesn't work (Runtime-error 3251) The wierd thing is that at another point a .find works perfectly fine with a recordset defined exactly the same way (on the same table just a diffrent column from the same datatype)...

Comment: @l.wach That's not surprising, the `Seek` method usually works on unique/index fields. However the syntax is probably not complete. I think you can try to apply it as in this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675770(v=vs.85).aspx    `rst2.Seek Array(messId), adSeekFirstEQ`

Comment: Seek is DAO only and not for linked tables.

Comment: @Gustav but it is listed here? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675841(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: @A.S.H: Yes. That's a surprise to me; I believed it was a DAO special. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use ADO very often, but 2 ideas I had neither very graceful-

1) `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rst2.GetRows)` (make sure to use `.MoveLast` and `.MoveFirst` first) to get an array of the recordset which you can then iterate through to find the ID you are looking for...

2) Same idea but just do it in the recordset...

Also, as others have previously mentioned a new query would certainly get you the value youre looking for...

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had this same issue and figured it out.  The issue was that the pointer for the recordset wasn't at the BOF and therefore, it couldn't find the value I was looking for because it was "above" the current place of the pointer.  The .Find doesn't wrap around to search the whole recordset.

I solved this problem by just adding a rs.moveFirst right before the .Find line.  This solved the problem.