# recordset.Find and return values in other columns from same record

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve specific data out of the results from a stored procedure. For this reason I can't use a simple query, and I am therefore trying to use `recordset.Find` without avail.

```vb
Public keys as ADODB.Recordset

Function getdata(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source= OMITTED" 
cnn.Open

Set getdata = cnn.Execute(query)
End Function

Private Sub link1box_Change()
Set keys = getdata("EXEC sp_fkeys @fktable_name = 'astAssets'")

End Sub
```

So far so good, but I can't seem to get the `Find` function to work on the keys recordset.

`If keys.Find("PKTABLE_NAME = 'astAssets'") Then Debug.Print "found"`
throws the following compile error on `.Find`

> Expected Function or variable

My ultimate goal is to find a specific value in the output from the `sp_fkeys` procedure, and return values from specific columns in the same record.

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677943/recordset-find-using-variable-vba-adodb

Comment: Will it work with the parenthesis? All the examples show without.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I am aware of this thread, but I was unable to get a solution out of it

Comment: @JacobH no, same error

Comment: Did you try, `keys.FindFirst "[PKTABLE_NAME] = 'astAssets' "`

Comment: @WEI_DBA that throws a `Method or data member not found` error on `.FindFirst`

Comment: Is there a way to debug that to see if there is any data in the dataset?

Comment: There is. I have the executed procedure open in SSMS and keys(0) also returns data

Comment: Can you put the dataset into an array and loop through?

Comment: I'm currently using a `Do...Loop` with `keys.MoveNext` to loop and  `keys.Fields("PKTABLE_NAME")` to check if the current record is the correct one, but that's an alternative to something I don't understand but want to start understanding. I don't want to avoid the issue